# OpenCV camera - can't get a video decompresser?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, webcam

I am using opencv C++ (2.4.13) on windows 10 (10.0.10586) to read some image frame from my webcam using the following code:

```
VideoCapture capture;
Mat frame;    
capture.open(-1);
if (!capture.isOpened()) { printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n"); return -1; }

while (capture.read(frame)) ....
```

Opening the cam was successful but `capture.read(frame)` failed, returning an empty frame.

My cam works well in windows 10's camera application.

I debugged into opencv source code and found that the problem is here:

```
hic = ICOpen( MAKEFOURCC('V','I','D','C'),
                      vfmt0.biCompression, ICMODE_DECOMPRESS );
```

with vfmt0.biCompression = 0x47504a4d  ( "MJPG" = motion JPEG  )

The `ICOpen` function returned zero so the whole progress failed. `ICOpen` is a windows API to get a compressor/decompressor of video streams.

Do I need to install additional decompressor or any configuration step to get cam work under openCV?

Comment: How you built opencv?

Comment: @MohamedMoanis I am using precompiled binary package from opencv.org.