# OpenCV Webcam, open successful, read fails

Tags: python, windows, opencv, webcam-capture

I am using opencv 4.5.1 with Python 3.9.4 on Win10.

Until now I used a Logitech C920 for video capture. But as I needed higher frame rates I bought a "[ELP FHD08S-LC1100](http://www.webcamerausb.com/elp-no-distortion-usb-camera-mjpeg-260fps-640x360120fps-720p60fps-1080p-cmos-ov4689-mini-usb-camera-p-265.html)" which supports up to 260fps via MJPEG.

Within the Windows 10 camera app, both webcams work just fine, but within opencv I am just getting empty frames from it.

To simplify my problem I use this piece of code another thread, which just checks all cameras and tries to read an image from them.
If I attach the logitech, it works fine, with the ELP the results look like the one below.

The closest questions I found here was this one, but it seems fairly old and contains no answer: [OpenCV camera - can't get a video decompresser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878249/opencv-camera-cant-get-a-video-decompresser)

Can someone please help me to get this one going?

```
import cv2

print (str(cv2.__version__))
is_working = True
dev_port = 0
working_ports = []
available_ports = []
while is_working:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(dev_port)
    if not camera.isOpened():
        is_working = False
        print("Port %s is not working." %dev_port)
    else:
        is_reading, img = camera.read()
        w = camera.get(3)
        h = camera.get(4)
        if is_reading:
            print("Port %s is working and reads images (%s x %s)" %(dev_port,h,w))
            working_ports.append(dev_port)
        else:
            print("Port %s for camera ( %s x %s) is present but does not reads." %(dev_port,h,w))
            available_ports.append(dev_port)
    dev_port +=1
```

Output: (ignore Port1, there is nothing attached to it)

```
4.5.1
Port 0 for camera ( 360.0 x 640.0) is present but does not reads.
Port 1 is not working.
```

Comment: `VideoCapture` constructor: pass `apiPreference=` explicitly as `CAP_MSMF` or `CAP_DSHOW` (try both) -- and don't ever `cam.get(<magic number>)` there are defined constants for that, `CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` and such

Comment: if VideoCapture can be opened, but reading a frame fails... that's interesting. certainly unexpected.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz "CAP_DSHOW" works! Many many thanks for this quick answer!

Comment: feel free to (search for, or else) open an issue on OpenCV's github about this. relevant information: the model of camera, and different behavior between DSHOW and MSMF. at least then the issue is documented.